# would grails work with mongodb or cassandra?

Tags: java, grails, cassandra

would grails work with mongodb or cassandra?

or would you simply be using their mvc engine and not taking advantage of the other benefits of grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, look at this plugin http://github.com/mpriatel/mongodb-grails.

Comment: so this will still maintain the built-in functionality like auto creation of update pages?

Answer (score 2):

http://github.com/wolpert/grails-cassandra

"This grails plugins provides a service to enable easy access to Cassandra
from within grails. It is not intended to be a GORM mapping layer."

Comment: "EOL NOTICE:
This plugin is not being worked on anymore. Instead, I recommend using Hector
as a dependency in your grails project, and use it directly. There is no
advantage to this plugin anymore."

Comment: In 2014 you should actually use the DataStax Java Driver: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver

Answer (score 1):

There is a new  mongodb plugin for grails made by the springsource team.

See this blog post.

http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/15/gorm-for-mongodb-new-milestone-richer-experience/